# Cmake list-get command

Tags: cmake

Why doesn't the following command work?

```
SET(MY_LIST a b c d)
LIST(GET ${MY_LIST} 0 HEAD)
MESSAGE("HEAD = ${HEAD}")
```

I want it to assign `a` to `HEAD` but instead I'm getting `NOTFOUND`.

I have already tried surrounding `${MY_LIST}` with double quotes and changing the index to 1 instead of 0 (don't know why someone would do that but it didn't hurt to try).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The [list commands](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/list.html) require an [unsubstituted](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html?highlight=cmake%20variables#variable-references) variable as the second argument, i.e.:

```
set (MY_LIST a b c d)
list (GET MY_LIST 0 HEAD)
message ("HEAD = ${HEAD}")
```

Comment: It's really not clear from the docs. It's bad that the CMake documentation does not contain usage examples. :-(

Comment: The worst thing is the differentiation between all the commands. For this command, it's strange you need an unsubstituted variable!

Comment: It gets simpler if you remember, that passing a list by value is very inefficient in CMake (as it is in other languages), so each time a CMake function asks you for a list, it will always do this by reference, i.e. by unsubstituted name.

Comment: Then the command won't work with literals, which is not orthogonal I think.